# How to add console when debugging VSIX project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vsx

How to add console to VSIX project in the way you can output to it at any place of extension, for example using `cout << "Hello"` or `logger.log("Hello")`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found yet is one implemented in [AddAnyFile extension](https://github.com/madskristensen/AddAnyFile/tree/master)

It is supposed to use output pane. In the above mentioned project it is implemented in the following way:

```
using Microsoft;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

internal static class Logger
{
    private static string name;
    private static IVsOutputWindowPane pane;
    private static IVsOutputWindow output;

    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider provider, string name)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        output = (IVsOutputWindow)provider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow));
        Assumes.Present(output);
        Logger.name = name;
    }

    public static void Log(object message)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        try
        {
            if (EnsurePane())
            {
                pane.OutputString(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex);
        }
    }

    private static bool EnsurePane()
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        if (pane == null)
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            output.CreatePane(ref guid, name, 1, 1);
            output.GetPane(ref guid, out pane);
        }
        return pane != null;
    }
}
```

This method is inconvient of course, but is better than nothing.